# I want to relist my state with .sort() but nothing changes in React.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I tried two different ways to solve this but I couldn't.

First of all, I tried list "A to Z", "Z to A", "Max to Min" and "Min to Max" with sort() method according to sorting type.

Secondly I tried to use only "sort()" for "A to Z" and only reverse() for "Z to A" but it's not worked again after that I changed my code to first step with "ctrl + z".

Here is my code on first step:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import AxiosInstance from "../helpers/Axios";
import Loading from "../components/Loading";

const TopCountries = () => {

    const [country, setCountry] = useState([]);
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [sortBy, setSortBy] = useState("A to Z");
    const [error, setError] = useState();

    useEffect( () => {
        AxiosInstance.get().then((response) => {
            setCountry(response.data.data);            
        }).catch((error) => {
            setError(error);
        }).finally(() => {
            setLoading(false);
        })
    }, [])

    const Check = () => {
        if (sortBy == "A to Z") {
            country.sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.region.name > b.region.name) {
                    return 1;
                }
            })
        } else if (sortBy == "Z to A") {
            country.sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.region.name < b.region.name) {
                    return -1;
                }
            })
        }
         else if (sortBy == "Min to Max") {
            country.sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.confirmed > b.confirmed) {
                    return 1;
                }
            })
        } else if (sortBy == "Max to Min") {
            country.sort((a, b) => {
                if (a.confirmed < b.confirmed) {
                    return 1;
                }
            })
        }


        return (
            country.map((countryInfo) => {
                return (
                    <tr>
                        <td>{countryInfo.region.name}</td>
                        <td>{countryInfo.confirmed}</td>
                    </tr>)
            })
        )            

    }


    const selectSortBy = (event) => {
        setSortBy(event.target.value)
    }

    const searchCountry = (event) => {
        setSearch(event.target.value)
    }

    if (loading) {
        return (
            <Loading></Loading>
        )
    } else if (error) {
        return ("error")
    } else {
        return (
            <div className="container coronavirusList">

                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <input type="text" placeholder="Search any country here" />
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr className="casesListFilter">
                            <th>
                                <label htmlFor="casesFilter">Sort By :</label>
                            </th>
                            <th>
                                <select name="sortBy" id="casesFilter" onChange={selectSortBy}>
                                    <option value="A to Z">A to Z</option>
                                    <option value="Z to A">Z to A</option>
                                    <option value="Min to Max">Min to Max</option>
                                    <option value="Max to Min">Max to Min</option>
                                </select>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Country</th>
                            <th>Cases</th>
                        </tr>
                        <Check></Check>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default TopCountries;
```

```css
ul {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     display: flex;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: space-between;
}
 li {
     list-style: none;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
     color: #004eaf;
}
 li :hover {
     transition: 200ms all;
     color: #004394;
}
 li * {
     text-decoration: none;
}
 p {
     margin: 0;
}
 .border-bottom {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #555;
}
 header.container {
     padding: 2rem;
}
 header.container nav {
     width: 100%;
}
 header.container li {
     min-width: 33.33333%;
     text-align: center;
}
 .coronavirusList {
     display: grid;
     place-items: center;
}
 .coronavirusList tr:nth-child(even) {
     background: #ddd;
}
 .coronavirusList td, .coronavirusList th {
     padding: 1rem;
}
/* LOADER */
 .loadingContainer {
     display: grid;
     place-items: center;
}
 .lds-roller {
     display: inline-block;
     position: relative;
     width: 80px;
     height: 80px;
}
 .lds-roller div {
     animation: lds-roller 1.2s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) infinite;
     transform-origin: 40px 40px;
}
 .lds-roller div:after {
     content: " ";
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     width: 7px;
     height: 7px;
     border-radius: 50%;
     background: black;
     margin: -4px 0 0 -4px;
}
 .lds-roller div:nth-child(1) {
     animation-delay: -0.036s;
}
 .lds-roller div:nth-child(1):after {
     top: 63px;
     left: 63px;
}
 .lds-roller div:nth-child(2) {
     animation-delay: -0.072s;
}
 .lds-roller div:nth-child(2):after {
     top: 68px;
     left: 56px;
}
 .lds-roller div:nth-child(3) {
     animation-delay: -0.108s;
}
 .lds-roller div:nth-child(3):after {
     top: 71px;
     left: 48px;
}
 .lds-roller div:nth-child(4) {
     animation-delay: -0.144s;
}
 .lds-roller div:nth-child(4):after {
     top: 72px;
     left: 40px;
}
 .lds-roller div:nth-child(5) {
     animation-delay: -0.18s;
}
 .lds-roller div:nth-child(5):after {
     top: 71px;
     left: 32px;
}
 .lds-roller div:nth-child(6) {
     animation-delay: -0.216s;
}
 .lds-roller div:nth-child(6):after {
     top: 68px;
     left: 24px;
}
 .lds-roller div:nth-child(7) {
     animation-delay: -0.252s;
}
 .lds-roller div:nth-child(7):after {
     top: 63px;
     left: 17px;
}
 .lds-roller div:nth-child(8) {
     animation-delay: -0.288s;
}
 .lds-roller div:nth-child(8):after {
     top: 56px;
     left: 12px;
}
 @keyframes lds-roller {
     0% {
         transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
     100% {
         transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
/* LOADER */
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! State must not be mutated, and `.sort` is in place. Try `setFoo(foo.slice().sort())`.

Comment: Thanks everyone, setFoo didn't work well but I found a solution a little bit weird.
It's about "<".If we change 
"a.region.name < b.region.name" to 
"b.region.name > a.region.name" and the same for others, it will be fixed.

Of course I am going to learn Vue.js after that.

Comment: I found what real problem.In firefox return -1 is not changing anythink.You must write return 1's way.In a nutshell it's not about < and > it's about return -1 and return 1.